# why all my variables are reset when surface Changed is called?

Tags: android

i have a class that extends surfaceview and implement SurfaceHolder.Callback
i am just trying to animate a simple bitmap with x and y position which it's position is updated with time

everything  works fine in my code except that whenever surfacechanged  method is called when changing from protrait to landscape position or opposite ,the x and y values are reset back to there default value

how can i keep the x and y position the same after the the surfacechanged method is called?
my next question is how can i keep my game orientation only protrait and never changed into landscape when surface changed is called?
any help would be great?

thx

Comment: The activity containing the surface is recreated on orientation change.  This is normal Android behaviour.  Please learn the activity life cycle.  You can force the activity to portrait only in the manifest.  Everything is documented at developer.android.com

Comment: thx i figure out how to make it protrait in the manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the AndriodManifest.xml

android:configChanges

> Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When
>   a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down
>   and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this
>   attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the
>   activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is
>   called.
>
> Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last
>   resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information
>   about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

So write it like this

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

BUT it is suggested to go through this

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

It is better to handle this issue in the

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Your code
}
```

Comment: `Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort.`  You even quote the documentation and still recommend it!  This is a nasty hack which is probably responsible for more crashes and bugs in Android apps than any other cause since it hides bugs in the life cycle callback handling for screen orientation changes but not for the other scenarios which cause the activity to be recreated - and which most developers don't even think about, let alone test.  -1.

Comment: thx man ,i read about the activity lifecyle it helps me  a lot